# Unable to use EchoPrint Native Library Fatal Signal 11

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk

I am trying to use the natively compiled echoprint library from :
https://github.com/gvsumasl/EchoprintForAndroid

When I import, I get two projects ,
one is named main (which i rename to echo library) 
and the other echoprinttestlibrary

I mark the echo library as a library project.
Also the java classes are inside a java folder, which i put them inside the source folder.

Also there is a folder named jniLibs inside the echo library  which I rename into "libs". It contains library called " libechoprint-jni.so" 
Trying to run it without renaming it was giving an error libechoprint-jni.so not found.
But after renaming it to libs solved that problem but I am getting this problem

```
01-19 20:00:33.845: A/libc(32024): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2, fault addr 0xf0ee8000 in tid 32097 (Thread-845)
```

And I dont know how to solve it. Please help

Comment: With that info is impossible to solve your problem. A Fatal signal 11 means that you are trying to access to a part of the memory that doesnt exist, so, put your code, the part that fail and we will try to help you.

Comment: @vgonisanz I am trying to make the library work

Comment: https://github.com/gvsumasl/EchoprintForAndroid

Comment: Here is a brief introduction to Android native crash stack interpretation: http://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/ndk-stack.html. Even if you cannot resolve the problem by yourself, this link gives you a hint of what info you should put in your post so that somebody else can help you.